# Why assign variables to empty curly brackets?

Tags: syntax, core-language

I am trying to read code and I see empty curly brackets. For example:

```
abc = {}
```

or

```
fort[x_] := Module[{}, more stuff here ]
```

How does *Mathematica* interpret this syntax? I can make some guesses, but I have not found anything in the documentation. I'm new at *Mathematica* so please be kind. :)

Comment: `a = {}` and `f[x_] := Module[{} , ...]` are very different use-cases. The latter is just the syntax of `Module` when you don't need to define any local variables within the `Module` (so you leave blank where otherwise you would put the definitions of these local variables). The former is setting `a` to be an empty list so that later on, you can fill it with elements (in *Mathematica*, this is actually usually not necessary, because you can make lists on the fly without loops much easier, typically).

Comment: `{}` is an empty list which you can join with or append/insert to later.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @march I'm curious. When would you ever want to use `Module` with no local variables?

Comment: @DavidZhang. I sometimes do it for the sake of readable code. Typically, I have some set of operations that I am wrapping into a function, and `Module` reads nicer than wrapping a compound expression in parentheses, in my opinion. There might be actual programmatic reasons for doing so, but I'm generally unaware of those.

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the `FullForm` of the expression `{}`, you see that you're not assigning "nothing", but an empty `List`:

```
abc = {}
```

is the same as

```
abc = List[]
```

That is, a `List` of zero length. `{a, b, c, …}` is merely syntactic sugar for `List[a, b, c, …]`, so `{}` is syntactic sugar for `List[]`.

What is a `List`? It's literally anything that has the `Head` `List`, so a priori it's not got any more meaningful interpretation. However, there are protections built into Mathematica which ensure that you can't add any more definitions to `List` that stop it from behaving just like… well, a (finite) list. (Those protections include the `Locked` attribute.)

That is, `List` is one of the few symbols in Mathematica which really, genuinely, always represent the same thing, no matter what else you manage to break. Nearly everything else in the language is subject to user redefinition, but `List` is always the same. We therefore feel safe in consistently assigning it the interpretation of a "finite ordered collection of elements", and conflating the purely syntactic symbol `List` with the semantic idea of a list.

Comment: Great tutorial. It lead me to review  "four kinds of bracketing", play with Length[{}} and got 0, Length[{1,2,3,,4}] and got 5. The double ,, put a Null in the list. and more! Good job.